# Select option in list with Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, web-scraping, safari

I'm using Selenium with Python to use [this website](https://www.edf.fr/groupe-edf/qui-sommes-nous/activites/optimisation-et-trading/listes-des-indisponibilites-et-des-messages/liste-des-indisponibilites) and want to change page by clicking on the button designed for that. However, and I don't know why, this button is disabled and becomes enabled only if you choose another number of items to be displayed on the page.

I managed to programmatically click on the list to display all the options but didn't manage to select an option.

[image]
I tried with the following lines:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-limit']/option[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='edit-limit']/option[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('50').click()
```

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a method for selecting option by value from dropdown list or select:

```
def set_select_element(self, element, val):

    element = ui.Select(element)

    return element.select_by_visible_text(val)
```

where element -- this is your select element on the page.

Comment: Could you tell me in which library I should find ui.Select(...) ? Thanks !

Comment: @AlexM, use the following: `from selenium.webdriver.support import ui`.

Comment: Thank you @Ratmir Asanov ! Unfortunately it doesn't work for me with these lines :
option_display = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("edit-limit")) followed by
option_display.select_by_index(3)

Comment: Ok, let's try with first dropdown from this site -- https://www.edf.fr/groupe-edf/qui-sommes-nous/activites/optimisation-et-trading/listes-des-indisponibilites-et-des-messages/liste-des-indisponibilites:
`element = ui.Select(driver.find_element_by_id("edit-statut"))
element.select_by_visible_text("Actif")`
Try this code, please, @AlexM.

Comment: @Ramir Asanov it finally works with Google Chrome, don't know why Safari is in trouble with this. Thanks a lot! Wish I could upvote your answer but I can't.